# How can one calculate volumetric efficiency without a MAF sensor?

Tags: obd-ii, maf, efficiency

I am completely new in the field of OBD2 sensor;
I am looking for a method (or a formula) to calculate Volumetric Efficiency of:

1. Diesel Car
2. Petrol Car

which do not have a MAF sensor. Can anyone help me with the method of calculating such or give a direct formula to that.

Data known are:

```
AIR_INTAKE_TEMP
ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP 
INTAKE_MANIFOLD_PRESSURE (MAP)  
ENGINE_LOAD 
ENGINE_RPM  
SPEED   
THROTTLE_POSITION   
FUEL_ECONOMY    
AIR_FUEL_RATIO
```

These data have been taken from OBD2 sensor.

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you are trying to achieve. My understanding of volumetric efficiency doesn't seem to fit your question.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no one-size-fits-all formula

Perhaps an analogy can help explain why this is.

The volumetric efficiency of an engine is analogous to a person's ability to fill their lungs with air.

To continue with the analogy, the various OBDII parameters are like a person's vital signs, such as heart rate, blood pressure and O2 saturation.

To say that the rate of lung fill between a smoker and non-smoker would be the same if their vital signs were identical would be wrong.

---

In similar vein (no pun intended), each engine has its own signature volumetric efficiency.

Don't get me wrong - yes it is possible to relate the various OBDII parameters to volumetric efficiency through an extensive mapping (which would involve bench-testing the engine in question) but even then this map would reflect the behavior of *only* the engine that was tested.

No guarantees can be given for other identically manufactured engines.

---

### In summary

Predicting volumetric efficiency with just OBDII parameters would be an exercise in futility.